# Linux console is one row too far up (in framebuffer mode, not in X=

Tags: linux, ubuntu, console

I installed Ubuntu Server 10.04. The console is one row too far up. I can't see the first line (the _ cursor is the only thing I can see from that line as it's too high up) and there is room for one more line at the bottom of the screen.

Is there a fix for this? It's a wide screen monitor, as most monitors there days.

Comment: This should probably be on http://superuser.com

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried adjusting your monitor yet? I see this all the time, and usually pushing the "Auto Adjust" button on an LCD monitor fixes it right up.